# objective-C basic concepts

Tags: objective-c, documentation

I have recently started developing iPhone apps without any prior theoretical knowledge about iOS or Objective-C, could someone tell where should i start reading about objective C ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How-to articles for iPhone development and Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-and-objective-c)

Answer (score 2):

An excellent starting point is the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html). There are some [good books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321811909) around, too.

After grasping the language constructs, your next stop for more specific information about any iOS controls, concepts and techniques, can be the [iOS Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/), which is full of guides, references and FAQs.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite site is given below, It includes most of the tutorials and stuff. Hope that helps you. Also you can start with [guide from apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html)

> http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials
>
> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/88929/Getting-Started-with-iPhone-and-iOS-Development

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the following link
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html

You can also use Objective-c tutorial by lynda.com